# Sharing a Typescript Virtual among projects

Tags: asp.net, typescript

I have an asp.net project that acts as as frontend and inside of it a set of typescript file that are the client part of the application.
Now I need to make a copy of the asp.net app, but I would like to share the same typescript virtual project among the apps.
I can keep the typescript files in the first project and add to the second one just the compiled javascript file, but I would like to know if there is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution to this would be to package your TypeScript application, for example as an NPM package.

To do this, it is best to compile with the definitions flag, so you beats JavaScript and type definitions.

The NPM package would just include the `.js` and `.d.ts` files.

This allows your second application to have some control over its dependencies, rather than getting surprise charges when the first application is changed.

Comment: yes, I read about this solution, but I think works badly inside a vs solution: I don't have a typescript project itself, I suppose I have to create a static project to work on it, and repackage every time I do a change. This could work when the ts application is stable, not during development